# How can negative total energy mean a bound state is potential zero is arbitrary?

Tags: energy, potential, potential-energy, conventions, hamiltonian

My Understanding is that if the Hamiltonian (H) plus potential (V) of a particle if negative than we have a bound state. However I also know that a potential is defined by placing a zero at an arbitrary place, by changing this place it should always be possible to get H+V to be positive and therefore not bound. What is wrong here?

Comment: Energies are measured *relative* to the potential energy at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

First, $H<0$ defines a bound state, not $H+V<0$ (the hamiltonian already includes potential energy).

To the question at hand, as mentionned in Bert Barrois' comment, what matters is energy relative to the energy of the particle at rest at infinity $E_\infty$. This removes the ambiguity in the constant.

If one chooses a reference elsewhere, the equation becomes $H<E_\infty$.